# Que no se actualice la hora al refrescar la pagina

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lo que quiero es que solo una vez obtenga la hora y al refrescar la pagina no cambie la hora porque es la hora de la ultima visita.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var time = new Date();
 document.getElementById("hora").innerHTML =  time.toLocaleString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric' , hour12: true })
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Hora</p>
<p id="hora"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola, cuál sería la lógica del script? Quien la ve actualizada o quien no debería?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En este caso vendría mejor trabajar con [**`localstorage`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

---

Primero tendrías que validar si existe un valor almacenado en el `localstorage`. Si existe, solamente mostramos en pantalla ese valor, si no existe, obtenemos la última hora y enviamos ese valor al `localstorage`, para que así en la siguiente vez que recarguemos la página, el valor ya existiría, cumpliendo el primer `if` (quien se encarga de mostrar sólo ese valor y no volverlo a actualizar).

---

##### Ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let valorStorage = localStorage.getItem("time"); // intentamos recoger el valor almacenado en el localstorage.

  if (valorStorage) { // si ese valor existe...
    document.getElementById("hora").innerHTML = valorStorage; // solo mostramos en pantalla.
  } else { // de lo contrario...
    // obtenemos la hora actual...
    let time = new Date();
    let formatoTime = time.toLocaleString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric', hour12: true });
    
    document.getElementById("hora").innerHTML = formatoTime; // mostramos la hora actual en pantalla
    localStorage.setItem("time", formatoTime); // y almacenamos la hora actual en localstorage
    
    // hasta aquí ya almacenamos el valor al localstorage, y al recargar la página, cumplirá el primer if ya que el valor existe, y ya no volverá a actualizar la hora actual.
  }

  // Probemos limpiar el localstorage
  $("#limpiar").click(function(){
    localStorage.removeItem("time");
    document.getElementById("hora").innerHTML = "";
  });
});
```

```html
<p>Hora</p>
<p id="hora"></p>

<button id="limpiar">Limpiar Storage</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Extrañamente, los *Snippets* de SO no permiten trabajar con `localstorage` (o la verdad no se que suceda), sin embargo, aquí te adjunto un [**ejemplo**](https://codepen.io/christopher-ps/pen/gOQOgNv) hecho en *CodePen* (en incógnito no funciona).

Comment: Muchas gracias Cris me funciona muy bien la solucion.

Comment: @Cris es una restricción del sandbox de los navegadores, en el que corren los ejemplos que pones en snippets en SO.

Comment: @jachguate gracias, no tenía entendido porqué ocurría eso.